# How to stop outbound ftp from being established. centos/ rhel

Tags: rhel, firewall, ftp

What is the method to block a machine from establishing connection to an outside ftp server. Both ftp and sftp.

inet, iptables, shutdown service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing, but it looks like you want to block connections to port 21 and port 22 .  This can be done on the host itself for ftp

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 \
-d the.rem.ote.ip \
-m comment --comment "blocked as per ticket##" \
-j REJECT
```

SFTP, though, is tricky:  it shares a port with ssh.  If you are okay with blocking the outgoing ssh connections too, then ^21^22 after that last command.  If you need to keep ssh and block sftp, you'd need to condition the remote end to never offer any sftp subcomment; or change your local config (not sure how) to prevent sftp of any kind (the challenge being users can download sftp binaries at any time).

Blocking port 21 and 22 on an intervening firewall you control is much more reliable, but that's not going to be a centos/rhel issue that you'd need to ask here.

I think if you can't block all port-22 access via firewalls, then you're in for a rough time.

Answer (score 0):

Using `iptables`

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p 21 -j REJECT      # FTP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p 22 -j REJECT      # SFTP et.al.
```

Do be aware that `sftp` uses port 22, which is also used by `ssh`.

If you want the process to be unaware then change the `REJECT` to `DROP`.

The rule above is obviously on the machine that you want to block. If you are configuring the rules on a router or other firewall device then you will need to be more specific as to interface and possibly IP address so as not to globally block this traffic.

Comment: Be aware `sftp` and `ssh`, **usually** use port 22. But a server can be configured to use any. Also a port forwarder can be set up on a 3rd computer. In general solving this problem by black-listing is impossible. White listing can do it, but is usually over restrictive. Logging and monitoring is another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer you can certainly block those ports (either on the machine or on a firewall on the way out)... but what if the connection is attempted using a non-standard port?

If you want to be truly paranoid, you can go the route of blocking all outbound traffic, and then taking the laborious path of adding rules explicitly for those ports/services that you want to allow. Much like configuring an inbound firewall that you fully lock down, this can take some time but will provide you with precise knowledge/control over the traffic passing out from your system.